# how to calculate the half-mass radius and tidal radius of a (simulated) globular cluster

Tags: n-body-simulations, star-cluster

I am exploring a [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/mariopasquato/star-cluster-simulations) of a direct N-body simulation of a star cluster, such that all particles have the **same mass** and

> G = M = −4E = 1

for the whole cluster. The data available is the **positions and velocities** of all stars (at certain snapshots of the simulation).

I'd like to be able to calculate some basic characteristics of the cluster. First I did the center of mass (which is just the mean of all coordinates since all masses are equal), but I am not sure how to proceed for these two:

- The half mass radius - I can't seem to find an established (i.e. most efficient) way to calculate this. My first idea is to use a bisection method with the center of mass and the total radius as starting points, and do window queries with a spherical envelope until it contains half the stars. Is there something more efficient than that?
- The tidal radius - what I've found so far always involves variables drawn from the galaxy the cluster is in (like the total mass of the galaxy and so on). However, this being a simulation, there is no such data. Yet the dataset states that some stars escape the cluster over the length of the simulation... I must be missing something here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first question is about computing, not astronomy. You find a cumulative histogram of distance from the centre of mass and where that reaches 50% of the stars.

As to your second point, there is no tidal radius; you need two bodies in order to have a defined tidal radius. The tidal radius of a cluster is directly related to the gravitational potential external to it.

Stars can escape from a cluster because sometimes they can accumulate enough kinetic energy in weak interactions with each other, that their speed exceeds the escape speed of the cluster. It is a classic result that the "evaporation" timescale is of order 100 times the cluster relaxation timescale, even in the absence of an external gravitational field (e.g. [Gerhard 2000](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0007258)).

Comment: Thanks, I checked out the paper. So in my case a star would (generally) escape the cluster if it's velocity is greater or equal than twice the root mean square of the velocities of all the stars ("Thus, on average, a particle with v≥2V=√12σ‖ will escape")